# Choosing Magian Trial Weapons with "+ Double Attack" VS "Occ. Attacks Twice"?

Tags: final-fantasy-11

What factors would drive a choice between choosing to build a Magian Trials weapon that gives "Double Attack" vs one that gives "Occ. Attacks Twice"?

My thought has been: would "+Double Attack" be more compelling for jobs/subjobs that already give a "Double Attack" ability, in which case, that's always better than "Occ. Attacks Twice", isn't it?

So, what would be the case where "Occ. Attacks Twice" wins?

Comment: Your thought is along the right track, but the the math behind this is very complicated, depending on a lot of things - job in question, other gear you're using, subjob of choice.  Like everything in FFXI it's VERY situational.  I'm not qualified to do the math on this, so I won't answer.  (I seem to recall that the Double Attack magians, in most situations, are not as good, but I may be remembering wrong.  Historically I know Double Attack tended to be inferior.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the landscape of old-school Souleater DRK Zerging is the major one for the following reason:  Double/Triple Attack (DA/TA) will override Occ. Attacks Twice (OAT), so DRK/NIN with a Kraken/Octave/MKris was always aware not to add either of the two to keep the number of OAT procs high.

So ignoring everything with respect to job, sub, damage types of the weapon, weapon skills etc. you can do pretty well with just Occ. Attacks X for raw damage if your %s are much higher than your DA otherwise would be.

That being said, DA/TA is usually better on the more intangible things. DA/TA procs on weaponskills, but OAT does not.  OAT weapons are usually horrifyingly low damage.  And if you are using Occ. Attacks 4x-8x weapons, you will turn whatever you're fighting into a TP spamming machine.

[A relevant DRK discussion can be found here on the subject](http://www.ffxivpro.com/forum/topic/27678/drk-resolution-gs-builds/9/), although it doesn't address the zerging aspect of things.  A quick Google around Blue Gartr and such should yield the old school discussions around this when Magians first started.